# What is the proper way to make options/settings view in iOS apps?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, comparison

What is the proper way to make options/settings view in iOS apps:

1. Use `UITableView` or `UICollectionView`
2. Implement static representation, draw cells, delimiters, customize handle taps etc.
3. Your way?

What I need is to speed up view creation of that type of UI.

Comment: It's kind of generic, that should depends of your need. You might want build a settings scene in your application as tableview or maybe an action sheet will be enough to your case.

Comment: This question is off topic - it depends on the app and is primarily opinion based

Comment: It is more of which thing according to design will be best fit for user experience.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [UIAlertViewController](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uialertcontroller) with `.actionSheet` style.

**Example:**

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Action for location", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)      

alertController.addAction(
    UIAlertAction(title: "One", style: .default) { action in
    // option clicked
})

//add more actions

present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**Appearance:**

[image]